# Bind table only if specific value doesn't using r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rbind

Is it possible to bind rows only where specific values are missing?

In this example I have a table with four ID's and some values. Every ID is suppose to have a corresponding value of 1-3. As you can see, some of these values are missing in table `dat`. To fix this I want to bind `dat` with `dat2`, but only where values from the column "value" are missing from table `dat`. How can I achieve this?

To be clear, I only want 12 rows in total. So for instance, ID 4 has the value 3 and cat_var "green" in table `dat`. By contrast, in table `dat2` ID 4 has the value 3 and cat_var "red". This means that I don't want to bind that row, since there already exists a row for ID 4 and value 3 in table `dat`. I hope I'm making myself clear.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Data:

```
id <- c(rep(1:4,3))
value <- c(rep(1:3, each = 4))
dat <- data.frame(id, value)
dat2 <- dat
dat <- dat %>%
  slice(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12)
dat2$cat_var <- c(rep("orange", 5), rep("green", 5), rep("red", 2))
dat$cat_var <- c(rep("orange", 3), rep("green", 5))
```

Desired result:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
      id value cat_var
   <int> <int> <chr>  
 1     1     1 orange 
 2     2     1 orange 
 3     3     1 orange 
 4     4     1 orange 
 5     1     2 orange 
 6     2     2 green  
 7     3     2 green  
 8     4     2 green  
 9     1     3 green  
10     2     3 green  
11     3     3 red    
12     4     3 green
```

Comment: I don't really understand your desired result with 12 cases from a bind rows. As it appears you replace the  4 3 red with 4 3 green. But if you really want bind rows (resulting in a 13x3 table) wouldn't a simple dat2 %>% bind_rows(dat) %>% distinct( do the trick?

Comment: I've edited the question and hopefully made it more comprehensible this time. Sorry for  the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat %>% bind_rows(dat2) %>% distinct(id, value, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  arrange(value, id)
```

results in :

```
   id value cat_var
1   1     1  orange
2   2     1  orange
3   3     1  orange
4   4     1  orange
5   1     2  orange
6   2     2   green
7   3     2   green
8   4     2   green
9   1     3   green
10  2     3   green
11  3     3     red
12  4     3   green
```

You dont need the arrange (it is just to get the exact same dataframe as the disered result).

Comment: Note it only gives the desired result because it removes the second duplicate and I made sure the duplicate from dat2 is second. You need to keep that in mind if you want a different order or in another situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R :

row bind `dat` and `dat2` and using `duplicated` keep unique rows.

```
result <- rbind(dat, dat2)
result <- result[!duplicated(result[, c('id', 'value')]), ]
result

#   id value cat_var
#1   1     1  orange
#2   3     1  orange
#3   1     2  orange
#4   2     2   green
#5   3     2   green
#6   4     2   green
#7   2     3   green
#8   4     3   green
#10  2     1  orange
#12  4     1  orange
#17  1     3   green
#19  3     3     red
```